# Вывод содержимого файла при нескольких совпадениях

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, файлы, сортировка

Необходимо реализовать класс отвечающий за поиск данных заданным пользователем в текстовом файле. Но есть одна проблема с которой не могу справиться: Пользователь вводит слова, которые записываются в массив(по крайней мере так сделал я), и вывод файла должен осуществляться лишь в том случае если минимум 2 слова введённых пользователем совпадают. Собственно на этом я и застрял. Мой код выводит содержимое файла лишь при совпадении всех введённых слов. Вот код:

```
public class startSearch{
String[] arr;
startSearch(String[] arr){
    this.arr = arr;
}
void print(){
    String search = "";
    for(int i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
        search = arr[i];
    }
    try {
        String y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\len\\Desktop\\none.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        if (y.contains(search)) {
            System.out.println("File is contain your search:" + search);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Как мне реализовать написанное выше?

**UPD**: Новый код:

```
public class startSearch{
String[] arr;
String help;
startSearch(String[] arr){
    this.arr = arr;
}
void print(){
    String search = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(i%2==0) {
            help = arr[i] + " ";
            search += help;
        }else {
            search+=arr[i];
        }
    }
    try {
        String y = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\len\\Desktop\\none.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        if (y.contains(search)) {
            System.out.println("File is contain your search:" + search);
            System.out.println(y);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Your request did not found");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: String search = "";
    for(int i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
        search = arr[i];
    }

у тебя уже здесь ошибка будет, в search будет последний элемент массива arr

Comment: @Санаев Увидел, переделал, посмтори UPD

Comment: так же название класса с Большой буквы,

Comment: @Санаев Но как мне выводить содержимое файла при совпадении лишь 2 слов?

Comment: очень просто, ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public class StartSearch {
    private List<String> arr;
    private final String PATH = "C:\\Users\\len\\Desktop\\none.txt";

    StartSearch(String[] arr) {
        this.arr = Arrays.asList(arr);
    }


    void print() {
        try {
            List<String> fileList = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (fileList
                    .stream()
                    .filter(s -> arr
                            .stream()
                            .anyMatch(s::equals)
                    )
                    .count() > 1) {
                System.out.println("File is contain your search:" + arr.toString());
                System.out.println(fileList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, честно в силу моего небольшого опыта даже не додумался бы, пока что:) Спасибо!

Comment: на будущее старайтесь не использовать массив строк

Comment: Похоже зря я просто скопипастил. Возможно я плохо разобрался в работе вашего класса, но при вхождении даже всех элементов метод StartSearch.print()    Ничего не выводит. Что я делаю не так:         String[] abc = {"zz","hh",};
        StartSearch startSearch=new StartSearch(abc);
        startSearch.print();

Comment: Компилятор пишет что в условии if  ")"  нужна.Выставил вот так: if (fileList.stream().filter(s -> arr.stream().anyMatch(s::equals)).count()>2). Верно? Но тогда этот код при вхождении 2 слов в файл не выводит ничего: StartSearch.print() Ничего не выводит. Что я делаю не так: String[] abc = {"zz","hh",}; StartSearch startSearch=new StartSearch(abc); startSearch.print();

Comment: проверяйте. >2 стояло, а нужно >1

Comment: Да! Все работает, правда только сейчас понимаю, что если бы пытался сам читать код то нашел бы недочёт. Большое спасибо.